# Tkinter / Python - Aligning Text in Character String (Project for Class)

Tags: python, tkinter

Am loading a listbox in TKinter.  The string is a collection of fields from a matrix.  4 fields, 1 date, 1 float, and 2 text.

However, because of proportional fonts, I cannot get the text in each line to line up into columns.

Here is my current code

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from datetime import *
import locale
# for currency display, set the locale
locale.setlocale( locale.LC_ALL, '' )



class main_gui(Frame):

    def __init__(self):                                                 #Intialize key variables and call the main screen.
        self.Ledgerdata = [ ]
        print ("main_gui __init__")
        self.load_data()
        self.main_screen()

    def load_data(self):
        # stub for testing - to be rewritten to read external file and load into Ledgerdata.

        entry = []
        entry.append("4/17/2016, 24, 1, Doctor")
        entry.append("4/18/2016, 32, 1, Mechanic whose name is bill")
        entry.append("4/19/2016, 45, 1, Grocery")
        entry.append("4/11/2016, 19, 1, Puppet")
        entry.append("4/17/2016, 119.50, 1, Johns Computer House")
        entry.append("4/11/2016, 1250, 1, Sidney Barthalmew")

        for entry_index in range(len(entry)):
            entry[entry_index] = entry[entry_index].split(",")

            date_conversion = entry[entry_index][0].split("/")  # Convert date from text string
            entry[entry_index][0] = date(int(date_conversion[2]),  # to datetime variable
                                         int(date_conversion[0]),
                                         int(date_conversion[1]))
            self.Ledgerdata.append((entry[entry_index][0],  # Add transaction to Ledgerdata
                                                        float(entry[entry_index][1]),
                                                        int(entry[entry_index][2]),
                                                        entry[entry_index][3]))
#====== Data from file is read and loaded into Ledgerdata

    #main_screen - main display screen for Ledgerdata
    #  Will show list of transactions, total for each category,
    #  with buttons to Add, Edit, Delete, Create Summary and Exit
    def main_screen(self):
        root = Tk()                                                     # reference to the GUI toolkit
        main_window = ttk.Frame(root)
        main_window.grid(row=0,column=0)                                # overall Frame
        display_frame = ttk.Frame(main_window)                          # list display frame
        display_frame.grid(column=0, row = 0)
        option_frame = ttk.Frame(main_window)                       # selection frame - to be written.
        option_frame.grid(column=0, row=15, columnspan=8)
        summary_frame = ttk.Frame(main_window)
        summary_frame.grid(column = 10, row = 0)
        summary_frame.columnconfigure(0, minsize=50)
        summary_frame.columnconfigure(1, minsize=250)

        #Start display frame

        list_header = Label(display_frame, width = 100,                  # Header line for List
                            font = 12,anchor = W,                       #    NEEDS CLEANUP
                            text = "   Date       Amount    Description                Code")
        list_header.grid(row=1)

        list_of_transactions = Listbox(display_frame,width =100, height = 20, font = 12)  #Generate listbox widget
        list_of_transactions.grid(row=2, column = 0)

        # Loop for number of transactions in Ledgerdata.  Loop adds formatted transaction info to list_of_transactions
        #   liststring object for display
        for x in range(len(self.Ledgerdata)):
            output_string = '{0:10}  {1:>8}  {2:<50} {3:<40}'.format(
                                                     str(self.Ledgerdata[x][0].strftime("%m/%d/%y"))
                                                     ,locale.currency(self.Ledgerdata[x][1], grouping=True)
                                                     ,(self.Ledgerdata[x][3])
                                                     ,(self.Ledgerdata[x][2]))
            list_of_transactions.insert(x,output_string)
            list_of_transactions.grid(row=x, column = 0)




        #main_window.pack()
        mainloop()


main_gui()
```

Anyone know how to get elements in strings to text to maintain the same width???

Thanks as always,
Darrell

EDITTED - Per request, added entire code segment that can be run.  I had to take this out of my main program, eliminate several parts that are not relevant to the problem at hand, and make some changes that do not affect the problem at hand.  So this is just a standalone testbed.

Comment: It would be useful if you can provide a working code sample where you can actually fast debug something and not just a snippet.

Comment: Thank you for hte feedback.  I had thought you were supposed to not post long sections of code.  My mistake.  I will work on puting this into usable format.  Problem is that it is 6 lines of an object file that calls three other of my object files, so I have to create a new file that can be worked on.

Comment: I have tried a few things but unfortunately, I could not provide a real good answer. The only thing I have come across is that if you are using Text widgets inside the Listview the formatting works but you then can select and edit the text. During the day I will try different things.